# From List of Set of String to a plain list

Tags: java, list, collections

Is there a way to convert a  `List<Set<String>> mainList` to a plain List, without iterating over elements?

For example this one has value:

```
mainList = {ArrayList@705}  size = 2
 0 = {HashSet@708}  size = 3
  0 = "A2"
  1 = "A1"
  2 = "A3"
 1 = {HashSet@709}  size = 3
  0 = "A6"
  1 = "A5"
  2 = "A7"
```

I would like to have a new list like so:

```
list = A2,A1,A3, A6, A5, A7
```

Comment: Do you mean without `Iterator<T>` or without iterating over elements?

Comment: Without iterating over elements. Straight on.

Comment: Well, you *can't* do it without iterating. You can use streams, but it will use an internal iterator.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: could you please show me the way?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat [You can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55473379/1898563) (or *could*) but not with every set or list implementation.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: you are right! Thank you for your honesty and 'other' solution.

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError can you please explain why you don't want to use iterators?

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError If you are going to implement the answer written by me then you can also use `.sorted()` or `.sorted(comparator)` after `.flatMap()` to get a sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Ordinarily, the only way to copy `n` things is to iterate over each of them.

The only way to avoid iterating over elements would be a lower-level operation like an array copy.

An `ArrayList` would do this (others like `LinkedList` would not) but no `Set` implementation in the JDK provides its own `toArray` implementation. They all use `AbstractCollection.toArray` which internally iterates over all of the elements.

If you implemented or found an array-based `Set` implementation (which would almost certainly not be an optimal `Set`, however) then you could flatten an `ArrayList<ArraySet<String>>` by using a series of array copies without iterating over the elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only curious about not using iterator, you can use simple for each loop to solve the purpose

```
    List<Set<String>> hs = null ; // Actual given List<Set<String>
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Plain List that will contain all the strings
    for(Set<String> set :hs) {
        arrayList.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(set)); // adding all the elements in list from hashset
    }
```

and with using streams(java 1.8 and above) in this way

```
    List<Set<String>> list = null ;
    List<String> al =  hs.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but can you please explain why you don't want to use iterators?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 1.8 and above, then you can use streams but it will still use an internal iterator. Here is an example:

```
List<String> list = mainList.stream() // create stream
    .flatMap(Set::stream)             // convert Set<String> to Stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList());    // collect to new ArrayList
```

Comment: "Without iterating over elements"

Comment: @Michael Atleast the answer is better than saying *You can't.*

Comment: [No it isn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer). It's perfectly valid. If not iterating over the elements is a requirement, my answer is correct. If it's not a requirement, this question is a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: @Michael I agree it's a valid answer, but arguing with JDK internals is relying on implementation details, which I don't think you should need to care about and might depend on and theoretically change between versions.

Comment: @daniu You could make the opposite point about this answer. I don't "know" that a stream iterates the elements. You could say that too is an implementation detail. Maybe the stream really doesn't iterate elements under the hood. Maybe it does some fancy JVM magic...

Comment: @Michael I meant to say I'd interpret the question as "without iterating _myself_", ie in user code. Ie I'd agree with your "duplicate" suggestion, but since your answer has been selected as correct, I guess that's what he was looking for.

Comment: @daniu Actually, my solution was selected as correct at first. But michael commented on the question and changed his mind. OutOfMemoryError asked me to write an answer, so I did. Anyways, nevermind :)